# Visual Studio 2015 - Two accounts signin error

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to add two accounts to my visual studio 2015 installation (my personal account for team foundation server and our company azure account for publishing to azure).

I can add both accounts separate (add first -> remove -> add second). But i cannot add both accounts at the same time. Look at this error:

> We could not add the account thankitsfriday@whynotworking.com
>
> user_interaction_required: One of two conditions was encountered: 1.
>   The PromptBehavior.Never flag was passed, but the constraint could not
>   be honored, because user interaction was required. 2. An error
>   occurred during a silent web authentication that prevented the http
>   authentication flow from completing in a short enough time frame

I tried everything i found on the internet.

- Reinstall
- Change network connection
- Change proxy
- ...

Any ideas?

Comment: Have a look at this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn872465.aspx

Comment: I add the second account exactly as described in the link but get the mentioned error message